# Regular expression to match a percentage with decimal?

Tags: regex, decimal, percentage, .net

I'm attempting to build a regular expression (.NET) to match a percentage with 4 decimal places. The 4 decimal places are required. The range looks like:

```
0.0001 to 100.0000
```

So far, I've come up with:

```
(?:[^0]+[1-100]{1,3})\.(?:\d{4})
```

However, I'm a bit unsure on how to add a few other requirements to this expression. I need:

- No leading zeroes before the decimal point. 42.4214 is allowed, 042.4214 is not. 1.0000 is allowed but 001.0000 is not. Etc..
- Up to 3 characters allowed before decimal without leading zeroes.
- If the number before the decimal is 100, do not allow the number after the decimal to be anything other than 0000, so 100.0000 is allowed, but 100.0135 is not allowed. (Is this even possible with a regex?)

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just treat the `100.0000` possibility as a separate case. It's easy to match that (`100\.0000`), and it's easy to match the rest (`[1-9]?\d\.\d{4}`), so with the two as alternates you get:

```
^(100\.0000|[1-9]?\d\.\d{4})$
```

(Assuming you want it to be the whole text, otherwise leave out the `^` and the `$`.

Comment: @mmdemirbas and I should hope not, the question defines the range as "0.0001 to 100.0000".

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Not sure why I never considered the 100.0000 as a separate case.

Comment: Well, there's the Teddybot-Effect (see http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/teddybot/ for the problem-solving wonder that is teddybot). Especially since as programmers we are always trying to make things not a special case as much as possible, you'd likely been looking at it for ages so what struck me and Daniel as obvious was going to keep passing you by. Sleeping on it and seeing it fresh might have been just as good, if not as quick as asking.

Comment: @JonHanna My mistake sorry :)

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
^((([0-9]|[1-9]\d)\.\d{4})|100\.0000)$
```

[Proof](http://regexr.com?31v3o)

Comment: Also perfect, wish I could mark two answers as correct. This definitely helps my understanding a bit, though - seeing it done two different ways. Thank you!

Comment: @DanielHilgarth OK, I missed the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

#### See it **[in action](http://regexr.com?31v4m)**:

```
^(0|[1-9]\d?)\.\d{4}|100\.0000$
```

#### Matches:

```
0.0001
100.0000
42.4214
1.0000
```

#### Doesn't match:

```
100.0135
042.4214
001.0000
000.0000
1000.0000
2000.0000
300.0000
```

Comment: Why do you even want to match 300? the range is 0.0001 to 100.0000

Comment: Looks good, except the range is 0.0001 to 100.0000 as others have mentioned. I do appreciate the link to that regex tester, much better than the cobbled together C# app I wrote. I almost want to set this thing as my homepage.

Comment: I forgot about the range. Fixed.