# Regex for percentages with or without decimals

Tags: php, regex

Im trying to use a regular expression to validate strings like:

```
1 %
12,25 %
99,99 %
100 %
100,00 %
```

Tried with this one from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12144501/1823209)

```
^(100\,00|[1-9]?\d\,\d{2}) %$
```

but i need the decimals to be optional and this one fails with strings like "90 %"

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Did you write the regex you show here? If yes, why can't you rewrite it? If not, please give credit to the person who wrote it and reason about what it does.

Comment: Updated with regex origin (thanks @Tomalak). I didnt write it and i'll use it with php. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/^(10{2}(?:,0{2})?|[1-9]?\d(?:,\d{2})?) %$/
```

The pattern allows a percentage of 100,00 or a 1 or 2 digit number (2-digit not starting with 0) optionally followed by a comma and 2 digits.

See [Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qQ4ut1/6) for matching, explanation, and efficiency.

Bonus features:

My pattern uses quantifiers on repeated characters to improve performance.
It doesn't use escaping slashes on commas -- they're not necessary.
It doesn't use more than one capture group, following the OP's pattern design.

Answer (score 1):

So, make the optional parts a capture group with `(...)`
and declare it optional by adding  `?`

Result:

```
^(100(\,00)?|[1-9]?\d(\,\d{2})?) %$
```

Matches:

- 10 %
- 10,20 %
- 100,00 %
- 100 %

Won't match:

- 10,2 %
- 200 %